# Solving $\frac{a_1}{1!}-\frac{a_2}{2!}+\frac{a_3}{3!}=\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: linear-diophantine-equations

> Solve $$\frac{a_1}{1!}-\frac{a_2}{2!}+\frac{a_3}{3!}=\frac{1}{3}$$
>   where $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are positive integers.

By trial and error, I found $a_1=1$, $a_2=5$, $a_3=11$.

I ask if there are others solutions. Thanks.

Comment: 1,3,5 would do.

Comment: do we have requirements that $a_1\neq a_2 \neq a_3$? etc

Comment: k, 2k, 2 for any integer k ?

Comment: @A---B I think that your solution is not general

Comment: You are looking for integer coordinates points of a plane $$6 x-3y+1z=2$$ in the positive orthant.

Comment: After you remove the enticing wrapping paper it is just a linear diophantine problem.

Comment: Yes, the factorials make the problem look more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 2):

The equation is equivalent to $$6a_{1}-3a_{2}+a_{3}=2
 $$ and there are infinite solution. It is sufficient to take $a_{3}
 $ such that $3\mid a_{3}-2
 $ and $a_{2}=\frac{6a_{1}+a_{3}-2}{3}
 $. For example $\left(1,1,11\right)$, $\left(2,8,14\right)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

All

$$a_3=2-6a_1+3a_2>0,$$ where $a_1,a_2>0$ are solutions.

There is a double infinity of them (in particular $(2n,m,2)$ with $m\ge n$).

Answer (score 0):

The equation is equivalent to $6 a_1 - 3 a_2 + a_3 = 2$ one solution (as just pointed out by A--B) $k,2k,2$. Other choices include taking $a_2 = n$, then you choose $a_1, a_3$ *st* $6a_1 + a_3 = 2 + 3n$. In fact, there are lots of solutions.

Comment: what about $1,3,5$ or $1,5,11$

Comment: I dont agree, (1,3,5) is a solution and is not of the form (k,2k,2).

Comment: Another independant **basic** family of solutions appears to be $(1,\ell,3\ell-4)$. By combining (in the sense of linear combination) it with the other family $(k,2k,2)$, one should get all solutions because of the affine plane interpretation given upwards.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think that the sentence "In fact, there are lots of solutions." is very informative.

Comment: I meant by that it is possible to set $a_1$ to a fixed number, then $a_3$ and meant it for an exercise for SADIK MOHAMMED to explore the other possibilities.